# How to get an organized search URL result with slashes orders (/)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a search section on the "index" from books_controller with some filter options from different authors, categories and other attributes. For example, I can search for a category "romance" and max pages = 200. The problem is that I'm getting this (with `pg_search` gem)

> http://localhost:3000/books?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query%5Btitle%5D=et&button=

but I want this:

> http://localhost:3000/books/[category_name]/[author]/[max_pages]/[other_options]

In order that if I want to disable the "max_pages" from the same form, I will get this clean url:

http://localhost:3000/books/[category_name]/[author]/[other_options]

It'll work like a block that I can add and remove.

What is the method I should use to get it?

Obs: [this](https://www.trulia.com/for_sale/Altoona,PA/1p_beds/SINGLE-FAMILY_HOME_type/) website, for example, has this kind of behavior on the url.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a route for your desired format and order. Path parameters are included in the `params` passed to the controller like URL parameters.

```
get "books/:category_name/:author/:max_pages/:other_options", to: "books#search"

class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def search
    params[:category_name] # etc.
  end
end
```

If other options is anything including slashes, you can use globbing.

```
get "books/:category_name/:author/:max_pages/*other"
"/books/history/farias/100/example/other"
params[:other]# "example/other"
```

So that gets you the basic form, now for the other you showed it could just be another path since the parameter count changed.

```
get "books/:category_name/:author/*other_options", to: "books#search"
params[:max_pages] # nil
```

If you have multiple paths with the same number of parameters, you can add constraints to separate them.

```
get "books/:category_name/:author/:max_pages/*other", constraints: {max_pages: /\d+/}
get "books/:category_name/:author/*other"
```

The Rails guide has some furth information, from "Segment Contraints" and "Advanced Constraints": http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints

If the format you have in mind does not reasonably fit into the provided routing, you could also just glob the entire URL and parse it however you wish.

```
get "books/*search"

search_components = params[:search].split "/"
#...decide what you want each component to mean to build a query
```

Remember that Rails matches the first possible route, so you need to put your more specific ones (e.g. with :max_pages and a constraint) first else it might fall through (e.g. and match the *other).

Comment: Thank you a lot! I just want to know something more: I have a hash with the params from the search form with :category_name, etc. So, on the controller I receive params[:search][:category_name] = "romance". What do I need to do to the application understand that this is the same :category_name specified on the router to make the url "books/romance" ?

Comment: params is somewhat like a hash already (see [`ActionController::Parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) allthough they will be direct only params (`params[:category_name]`) rather than a sub object (`params[:my_form][:category_name]`). You can always convert the parameters you need to an actual hash if needed

Comment: What I mean with my question, in other words, is that the action 'search' is going to receive from the form a hash[:search] with :category_name as one of his keys. The question is: Can the router recognize it automatically or I should do something to make it to know that now I want: "books/param[:search][:category_name]/" ?

Comment: You cant do like `books/param[:search][:category_name]`. Path params are always contained as `params[param_name]` no sub object. So change your action from having say `params.require(:search).permit(:field_a, :b, :c)` to `params.permit(:field_a, :b, :c)` or otherwise, `[:search]` wont exist any more in the action.

Comment: Thank you @Fire Lancer ! You saved my day!

Comment: I did what you sad and didn't work. I changed from `params.require(:search).permit(...)` to `params.permit(...)` and the params are the same format. I guess that it is something on the form itself...The other problem is that when I apply `get "books/:something", to "books#index"` the there is no path to reach this URL, like "books_path" associated. So I cannot get to go there...thanks.

Comment: you can use `as: :books` or such to give specific routes names you like. What URL did the form create? You didnt mention the client side or what helpers you are using so I assumed you had that sorted (e.g. some JS to convert a `<form>` into the URL you like)?

Comment: I used the `as: :books` and it is working now, thanks! I'm not using JS to make this conversion. My form is: 
 ` <%= simple_form_for :search,  url: books_path(:category), :method => :get do |f| %>
  <% f.input :category %>
  <% f.submit "search" %>
 <% end %>` 
I did some tests and this form is redirecting to: "/books/category..." but I want: "/books/romance...". I tried to change the param[:category] = param[:search][:category] on the controller and it didn't change the URL.

Comment: Its putting the `/category` there because you did `books_path(:category)` and so it took that as a string parameter. Seeing if SimpleForm can do it for you I think is *another question*.     Some JavaScript is required, you need a dynamic `action` on the `form`, HTML wont do that alone so somthing needs to handle the `submit` JS event and generate it.

Comment: Yes, perfect. Wow, nice job...the URL path depends on the user choice and books_path("user_choice") needs to change on the page dynamically and in time. It's strange that rails stills don't have tools for it. My doubts are solved now!